# Keep track of filepath while browsing multiple directories

Tags: php

Using this code from a previous post on **displaying a directory**

```
<?php 

      $files = array();
      $dir = opendir('races/ob/'); // open the cwd..also do an err check.

      while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
              if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php")) {
                      $files[] = $file; // put in array.
              }   
      }

      natsort($files); // sort.

      // print.
      foreach($files as $file) {
              echo("<span class='txt-spacing'><a href='$file'>$file</a> <br />\n</>");
    }
?>
```

My question is how do I make the links that are generated goto the correct filepath on the server, which then open in a new page and show all the file listings which are .txt files for users to click and view the data.

My directory structure is this

```
     Races
        |
       OldBird
            |
          Clubs Name Listing
              |
            List all .txt files for users to view
```

Comment: As it stands, your code doesn't recursively iterate the folder structure.  It will only scan the `races/ob/` directory.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes I would it to only scan races/ob/ I have another div setup for the  other part which is yb (for pigeon racers and the stats :D ) Currently it shows all the folder names for the clubs but I cannot click into that folder and load the txt files on a new page ;/  example of it is at [races.crpu.ca](http://www.races.crpu.ca) if that helps for the idea

Comment: Have you considered using a database instead?

Comment: @PeeHaa I would really love to use a db but they person who wrote the code to process the race results submitted by email wrote it rebol and then the program coverts it over to .txt, it' a big mess at the moment  maybe once I get a bit more knowledge on php I can re-write the script :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function scandir_recursive($path)
{
    if ($result = scandir($path))
    {
        $scan = $result = array_filter($result, function ($a) { return !in_array($a, ['.', '..', 'index.php']); });
        foreach ($scan as $sub)
            if (is_dir($subdir = "$path/$sub"))
                if ($dir = scandir_recursive($subdir))
                    $result = array_merge($result, array_map(function ($a) use ($sub) { return "$sub/$a"; }, $dir));
    }
    return $result;
}

$files = scandir_recursive('races/ob');
natsort($files);
foreach ($files as $file)
    echo("<a class='txt-spacing' href='$file'>$file</a><br>\n");
```

Comment: the code is listing everything at once, not once I click on one of the club names then goes into the club folder to generate the list of files, How could I modify it to do that ? Hopefully I'm clear enough on my question.

Comment: Thanks I just had to add path before the $file ( <a href='races/ob/$file'>$file</a> )