# Php Show Files after listing directory (Part 2)

Tags: php, arrays, directory

This is a part two to my previous question that got answered [Php Browsing Multiple Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813739/php-browsing-multiple-directories)

Now that I got the script reading the directories perfectly, Is it possible to load the results of the file listings into a new page like races.php to "pretty it up"

Here is how it's listing the files [Example of Files being listed from server](http://www.crpu.ca/backend/backend/2014/ob/CapitalCityRPA/) 
I would really like to have that be displayed inside of the site instead of jumping out into a apache server listing so its more user friendly.

**EDIT**
I think what I'm trying to do in theory that is once the script scans the dir it puts it into an array called $files I then foreach loop it for all of the folders but where I get stuck now is how do I pass that $file into a new page ? and make it show the contents inside the folder :)

Thanks again and sorry super newbie here trying to learn!

Script File to generate list and click to files inside of each:

```
<?php 

      $files = array();
     $dir = opendir('races/ob/'); 
      // $dir = opendir('races/ob/');

      while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
              if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php")) {
                      $files[] = $file; // put in array.
              }   
      }

      natsort($files); // sort.

      // print.
      foreach($files as $file) {
              echo("<span class='txt-spacing'><a href='races/ob/$file'>$file</a> <br />\n</>");
      }


     ?>
```

Comment: so um er put the script where you um er want to ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: what's currently stopping you from putting it in races.php or any other file ?

Comment: How do I make the link load that up correctly ?

Comment: you need to give a fuller explanation of the current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem with some help from a friend.  I hope others can use this to help out the community.

1) First thing is to list A directory of files on the index.php

2) Once the user clicks the generated folder, go into races.php and display the the results of the files listed inside the folder clicked.

Here is how it's done by passing a parameter in the URL

index.php

```
<?php 

             $files = array();
             $dir = opendir('races/ob/'); 

             // $dir = opendir('races/ob/');
                        while(false != ($file = readdir($dir))) {
                       if(($file != ".") and ($file != "..") and ($file != "index.php")) {
                                        $files[] = $file; // put in array.
                                }   
                        }

                        natsort($files); // sort.

                        // print.
                        foreach($files as $file) {

                          $url  = "races/ob/$file";

                          $path = urlencode($url);

                           echo("<span class='txt-spacing'>
                             <a href='races.php?race=$path'>$file</a> <br />\n</>");
                        }


                       ?>
```

races.php

```
<?php

      $path = $_GET['race'];


      // right here, you need the path prefix

      $path = '/public_html' . urldecode($path); //SERVER PATH


      // above here you need it

      $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

      $fileData = array();

      foreach($objects as $name => $object){

        $fileinfo = pathinfo($name);

        if (!is_dir($name) && isset($fileinfo['extension'])) {

         $file = $fileinfo['basename'];


         $fileData[] = $file;

        } 

      }
```

?>

```
          <?php foreach($fileData as $file): ?>

           <a target = '_blank' href="http://crpu.ca<?php echo urldecode($_GET['race'])                   . '/' . $file; ?>"><?php echo "$file<br>"; ?></a>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple function can do all for you

```
scandir(<path>);
```

It will give you list of all files in the directory.

Comment: I was hoping for an example of how to do that with the links which are already generating them just unsure of how to make it all work together!